# Internet connection activ only after restart of nftables

Tags: networking, router, firewall, nat, nftables

I configured a DIY Debian-based router without DHCP and DNS server.

**MY PROBLEM:**
When I switch on the router and the system boots, the Internet connection on clients becomes available for 4 -5seconds (Internet Icon on Win10 client becomes active), then drops and becomes available only after I restart nftables. How can I enable Internet connectivity permanently without restarting nftables?

I'm very new to Linux and nftables and would appreciate your support!
PS. I decided not to use OpenWRT and pfsense, because I also want to deploy and learn podman technology.

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

define carbon_LAN=eno2
define WiFi_LAN=eno1
define myWAN=enp2s0f1

table inet filter {
        chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0;

                # "drop invalid packets"
                iif $myWAN ct state invalid drop

                # "allow local packets"
                iif {$carbon_LAN,$WiFi_LAN} accept

                # "allow established wan packets"
                iif $myWAN ct state {established, related} counter accept

                # "allow communication between LANs subnets"
                iif $carbon_LAN oif $WiFi_LAN accept
                iif $WiFi_LAN oif $carbon_LAN accept

                # "drop the rest of the packets"
                iif $myWAN drop
                }

        chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0;

                # "drop invalid packets"
                iif $myWAN ct state invalid drop

                # "allow wan est, relat"
                iif $myWAN oif {$carbon_LAN,$WiFi_LAN} ct state {established, related} counter accept

                # "allow lan to wan"
                iif {$carbon_LAN,$WiFi_LAN} oif $myWAN counter accept

                # "drop the rest of the packets"
                iif $myWAN drop
                }

        chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0;

                # "allow traffic from all LANs to WAN"
                oif $myWAN accept

                # "allow communication between LANs"
                iif $carbon_LAN oif $WiFi_LAN accept
                iif $WiFi_LAN oif $carbon_LAN accept

                # "drop the rest of the packets"
                oif $myWAN drop
                }
        }


table nat {
        chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority 100;
                oif $myWAN counter masquerade comment "masquerade"
                }
        }
```

I have tried to add these rules without success into input chain

```
    # allow tcp DNS
    iif $myWAN tcp dport 53 accept

    # allow udp DNS and DHCP
    iif $myWAN udp dport {53,67,68} accept

    # allow ICMP on the LAN
    iif $myWAN ip protocol icmp accept
```

and this one into forward chain

```
 # "forward DNS"
   iif $myWAN oif {$carbon_LAN,$WiFi_LAN} tcp dport 53 accept
   iif $myWAN oif {$carbon_LAN,$WiFi_LAN} udp dport 53 accept
```

Comment: Compare `nft list ruleset` from before and after the restart.

Comment: @TomYan you are a ginous! The list is empty before restarting nftables. I have configured my rules in /etc/nftables.conf, but there is probably "flush ruleset" somewhere during the boot process. Is it a good practise to use /etc/nftables.conf? Or rather configure the nftables during the boot process?

Comment: Hmm, you sure the service that reads the conf (i.e., the one you restart) is *enabled*? (Or have you been "restarting" by running `nft` manually / directly?)

Comment: I thought I have enabled nftables with "systemctl enable nftables" command. Have found now that after Debian boot "sudo systemctl list-units" shows nftables status as "loaded failed failed". Previously I have activated nftables with "systemctl restart nftables". If "systemctl enable nftables" is the right command to permanently activate nftables, do I potentially have a conflict?

Comment: Well, you'll have to check why it failed to start upon boot, e.g. `journalctl -b -u nftables`. (My guess would be the use of `iif`/`oif` instead of `iifname`/`oifname`. IIRC the former would fail if the corresponding interface does not "exist" yet upon the rule insertion. I don't know if the latter pose any caveat like performance impact though.)

Comment: Dear @TomYan, thank you very much! You are right. journalctl shows me errors "Error: Interface does not exist... define carbon_LAN=eno2". In the documentation it says, that iif is faster - at what boot stage would interfaces "exist" upon the rule insetion?

Comment: There's no such general "stage" for physical interfaces because technically they can be plugged it anytime (even after the "boot process"). In reality (i.e., for devices plugged in before that begins), it depends on how fast the hardware and driver can response to enumeration. You probably can "stall" the nftables service start by adding a `[Unit]` section snippet with `After=` on `.device` of all the interfaces that are involved though. (See `systemctl edit`.) I don't consider it exactly a good approach but I am not sure if there's a better one (that is not racy) either.

Comment: Dear @TomYan thanks a lot for your support and saving so much time of mine! I decided to stick to iifname/oifname for the moment and will check now, how system behaves over time. At some point I will switch to iif/oif: there is enough material on Internet for different options.

Answer (score 0):

use of iifname/oifname instead of iif/oif solved the problem.